# Equivalent Force: Hydraulic rams in H frame machine press

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pressure, statics

A 100ton H frame machine press can use 1x100 ton ram to exert this amount of force.

Can 3x33 ton rams do the same job if they are applied to same area as the 100ton ram?

Also in relation to a H frame does the bed hanging rods/bolts take most of the ram force or do the legs disperse the force as well as support weight.

My apologies if this is a very basic question or if the basic understanding is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Pressure is force * area so what area are you working with?

How will you keep all 3 rams synchronised? Ie same pressure at he same moment?

The support bolts share the total load so if there are 4 each support or resists 1/4 of the load. Same for the frame legs - if there are 2, then each supports half the load.

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. Was thinking either 3 seperate small pumps or one singular large pump with exit connection splitting into 3 hoses to connect to each pump. So the whole structure takes the 100 ton load and that load is split equally amongst the loads since it is a uniform load?

Comment: The area in question is 200mm2 maybe since, it's so small might be easier to use a single 100ton ram?

Comment: @SolarMike A Whippletree keeps the jacks synchronised. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whippletree_(mechanism)

Comment: @DDuck show one of those controlling 3 hydraulic rams for 100 tonnes...

Comment: On the spreading of the load from a single point to 3 points, the answer is correct, as the nature of the load has changed from a concentrated load to a line load with lesser intensity, the result of the work will be different.